# Pagination Broken on Static Pages but Works on Blog Articles

Tags: plugins, permalinks, pagination

Our live site has a staging site.

All plugins have been updated to the most recent version on the live site.
The plugins have not been updated on the staging site.
The website does not have a plugin for pagination.

On the live site, the pagination stopped working for all static pages, but the pagination does work for blog articles.
The pagination will show `1 2 3 4 5 6 Next >>`
If you select any page number, the current page (page 1) just reloads and never goes to the next page.
The staging site pagination works for both static pages and blog articles.

The mentioned static pages use the plugin 'Advanced Custom Fields'.

Seems like some sort of issue going on once the plugins have been updated.
My plan to temporarily fix the pagination on the live site is to revert all plugins on the live site to the same version as the staging site.
But I still need to find out what is causing the pagination problem.

**UPDATE:** After reverting the plugins the pagination is still broken. I might try downloading all plugins on the staging site and uploading those plugins to the live site. This would include plugins that have been deleted and no longer in use on the live site. Plugins are the only thing I can think of that would have broken the static page pagination since the staging site is a copy of the staging site, and only the plugins would be a difference between the two sites.

**Pagination for Pages:**

```
  <div class="vpagination">

  <?php
  // Pagination
  echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => get_permalink() . '%#%' . '/',
    'format' => '?page=%#%',
    'current' => $page,
    'total' => $pages
  ) );
  ?>
 </div>

<?php else: ?>

  No vehicle found
```

**Pagination for Blog Articles:**

```
    <?php

    // Pagination
    if (function_exists("emm_paginate")) {
        emm_paginate();
    } ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Permalink:**
Using Custom Structure.

```
https://www.website.com / %category%/%postname%/
```

(I added a space before and after the "`/`" to show the actual permalink because I kept getting a weird permalink when pasting it here)

I am at a loss on what could be causing this pagination issue. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: By "static pages", you mean posts of the `page` type? Or is it any archive-based pages like category archives (e.g. `example.com/category/foo-bar`) and search result pages? Have you tried flushing the rewrite rules (just visit the permalink settings admin page)? And with the pagination for your "static pages", try with just `echo paginate_links();` - i.e. use all the default args.